# Server-Side Paging MVC 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, paging, server-side

I have MVC project with WCF service.

When I display a list of data, I do want to load everything from the database/service and do a client paging. But I do want a server-side paging. If I have 100 records and my page size is 10, then when a user clicks on page 1, it will only retrieve the first 10 records from the database and if a user clicks on Page 3, then it will only retrieve the corresponding ten records.
I am not using Angular or any other bootstrap.

Can someone guide me how to do it?

```
  public ActionResult Index(int pageNo = 1)
    {
        ..
        ..
        ..      

        MyViewModel[] myViewModelListArray = MyService.GetData();           

        //when I create this PageList, BLL.GetData have to retreive all the records  to show more than a single page no. 
        //But if the BLL.GetData() was changed to retrieve a subset, then it only shows a single page no.
        //what I wanted to do is, show the correct no of pages (if there are 50 records, and pageSize is 10, then show 
        //page 1,2,3,4,5 and only retrieve 10 records at a time.
        PagedList<MyViewModel> pageList = new PagedList<<MyViewModel>(myViewModelListArray, pageNo, pageSizeListing);
        ..
        ..
        ..
        return View(pageList);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code showing us what you have tried, and isn't working? It would go a long way to showing everyone what sort of environment you are working in and the style of coding that you are using.

Comment: please show some code. You might also try passing a start and limit to the server in order to tell to the server what specific set of records should be return.

Comment: @bogzy If I limit what specific set of records to be returned by passing in PageSize and PageNo, then it only showed a single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add paramters page size and page number to your service method and make the result an object which returns TotalCount and a List Items (Items being the items on the current page). Then you can use those values to create the PagedList.

Inside your business logic code you will do two queries one for the count of items and one for the items on the page.

Also if you are starting the project now do yourself a favor and remove the useless WCF service from your architecture.

Comment: Which property do I set for the TotalCount in PaedList?

Comment: You don't use the PagedList. If you want to use the rendering features (the html helper methods) you can implement this interface in your own class - https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/IPagedList.cs

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use LINQ to Entities operators Skip & Take.

For example, to page

```
int items_per_page = 10;
MyViewModel[] myViewModelListArray = MyService.GetData().OrderBy(p => p.ID).Skip((pageNo - 1) * items_per_page).Take(items_per_page).ToArray();
```

NOTE: The data must be ordered, so the pages have some consistency (but I did by an arbitrary field ID). Also some databases required 'order by' to apply 'limit' or 'top' (which is how Take/Skip are implemented).

I put it that way, because I dont know how you are retrieving the data.
But instead retrieving the full list with GetData and then filtering out, better include the pagination in the query inside GetData (so you don't retrieve unnecessary data).